# Problemas con el Combobox

Tags: c#, windows-forms, combobox

Estoy trabajando en Visual Studio con WinForms. Realizo el databinding con el combo box de la siguiente manera.

```
cboCurrentSaison.DisplayMember = "Code";
cboCurrentSaison.ValueMember = "ElementID";
cboCurrentSaison.DataSource = eleSaiCur.Elements;
```

Cuando realizo el ingreso de datos y guardo en la base de datos funciona bien. En la siguiente funcion intento mostrar la informacion de un producto recuperado de la base de datos de la siguiente manera:

```
private void ProductTotext(clsScenario Sce)
{
    int var = Sce.CurrentSaison();
    lblInfo.Text = var.ToString();
    txtCode.Text = Convert.ToString(Sce.ScenarioCode);
    txtCreatedD.Text = Convert.ToString(Sce.CreatedDate);
    txtCreatedU.Text = Convert.ToString(Sce.CreatedByUserID);
    txtDesc.Text = Convert.ToString(Sce.ScenarioDesc);
    txtModifiedD.Text = Convert.ToString(Sce.ModifiedDate);
    txtModifiedU.Text = Convert.ToString(Sce.ModifiedByUserID);
    cboStatus.SelectedIndex = Sce.ScenarioStatus;
    cboCurrentSaison.SelectedValue = Sce.CurrentSaison();
    cboPreviousSaison.SelectedValue = Sce.PreviousSaison();
}
```

Los metodos Sce.CurrentSaison() y Sce.PreviousSaison() recuperan el valor(tipo int) que corresponde al valuemember con el objetivo de mostrar en el combobox el displaymember. Este intento no funciona, alguna idea?

Comment: Buenos dias Juan. Pudieras especificar que tecnologia estas utilizando? Si Winforms, MVC o WebForms? No queda claro ese punto.

Comment: Lo siento. Olvide ese detalle. WinForms. Gracias!!!

Comment: Aclarame algo, al inicio le asignas un string al combo `cboCurrentSaison`: `cboCurrentSaison.ValueMember = "ElementID";` pero luego mensionas que el metodo `CurrentSaison()` retorna un intero. Es esto un ejemplo le estas asignado 2 tipos de datos diferentes?

Comment: Entiendo tu punto voy a revisar. Gracias!!!

Comment: @Einer en valuemember no está asignando ningun string, sino el nombre de la propiedad entiendo yo. Juan. de que tipo es eleSaiCur.Elements?

Comment: en especifico, el eleSaiCur.Elements[0].ElementID

Comment: en el value coloca esto Convert.ToInt32(Sce.CurrentSaison());

Comment: Si según el op _Sce.CurrentSaison() y Sce.PreviousSaison() recuperan el valor(tipo int)_ el método `CurrentSaison` ya devuelve un `int`...en que ayudaría `Convert.ToInt32`?

Comment: revisando tu código no deberías quitar los paréntesis de tu variable int???

Answer (score 0):

El problema era el siguiente: La clase que contiene ElementID es de tipo int. Pero cuando hice data binding utilice un string, ya que el valor venia de la base de datos. Por lo tanto los metodos Sce.CurrentSaison() y Sce.PreviousSaison() debian recuperar el valor en string en lugar de int.

Gracias, sin sus aportes no habria podido encontrar el problema.